# Retrieving process id using sshcmd on unix

Tags: awk

I want to retrieve process id  when my code successfully start the job. But its returning null.

I am starting job using sshcmd, creating log of sshcmd output, and then trying to retrieve process id in new_process_id using sshcmd. if I get new_process_id I will show new_process_id  else I will show output collected in log file. But I am getting null in  new_process_id.

```
remote_command="nohup J2EEServer/config/AMSS/scripts/${batch_job}  & "
sshcmd -q -u ${login_user} -s ${QA_HOST} "$remote_command" > /tmp/nohup_${batch_job} 2>&1

remote_command=$(ps -ef | grep ${login_user} | grep $batch_job | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}');
new_process_id=`sshcmd -q -u ${login_user} -s ${QA_HOST} "$remote_command"`

runstatus=`grep Synchronized. /tmp/nohup_${batch_job}`


if [[ $runstatus != "" ]]
then
 new_process_id=`cat /tmp/nohup_${batch_job}`
fi

echo $new_process_id
```

Comment: what's the content of /tmp/nohup_${batch_job}?

Comment: it is the log which will catch output of sshcmd execution

Answer (score 0):

The second variable `remote_command` is the output of that command run on your local machine.

Some other hints: If you are making a second, unrelated variable, give it another name. It will avoid unnecessary confusion.

What you are attempting to do next with runstatus and rewriting an already existing but not used variable is totally unclear to me.